# Cambiar opción de una web desde C#

Tags: c#

Quiero hacer con Windows Form cambiar de opción de una web de GMail. En este caso pongo [el enlace](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps). Desde la Web puedo poner **Sí** o **No**. ¿Existe esta posibilidad controlar esa opción desde C#?

Por supuesto que tendrás que poner en C# los datos la cuenta GMail, eso seguro.

Comment: No creo que puedas acceder a esa funcionalidad vía API. Esa funcionalidad es parte de Gmail y además siendo de seguridad más complicado.

Comment: La página enlazada no tiene un "Sí/No". Deberías aclarar la pregunta para que sea evidente qué es lo que quieres y poner el código que has intentado y el resultado que obtuviste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analizando las `api` de `gmail` que expone google

[Flexible, RESTful access to Gmail features](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)

Si nos enfocamos en la documentacion de la `settings`

[Users.settings](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings)

no hay ninguna que haga referencia a la opcion que buscas cambiar.

Se me ocurre que podrias interactuar con la pagina usando el control `WebBrowser`, con este podrias autenticarte he interactuar con el `html` para realizar acciones

[WebBrowser Control (Windows Forms)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/webbrowser-control-windows-forms)

por ejemplo podrias accionar un boton

```
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    webBrowser1.Document
        .GetElementById("button1")
        .InvokeMember("click");
}
```

la idea es trabjar en el evento `DocumentCompleted` y desde alli conocer el html para poder seleccionar el elemento que se quiere realizar una accion

Comment: ME da problemas en el click.

System.NullReferenceException: 'Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto.'

System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument.GetElementById(...) devolvió null.

Comment: que click? quizas este definiendo de forma incorrecta el selector y no encuentre el tag html que estas seleccionando, debes conocer el html inspeccionando lo que genere la pagina